# Database design: I want a column value to determine which table to query

Tags: sql, database-design

I don't have much experience in designing databases. I want a column value to determine which table to query, and I don't know if there is a better method for this. Here is the concrete problem for better understanding:

I am designing a database for a survey creator application. I want to store different kind of questions (for example: multiple choice questions and basic text question). I have the following tables:

```
QUESTION 
| ID | Title                        | TypeID |
----------------------------------------------
| 1  | "Pick a num from 1-10"       | 1      |
| 2  | "Choose some from the list:" | 2      |

TYPE
| ID | Name                  | ExtraValues |
--------------------------------------------
|1   |Scale Question         |ScaleValues  |
|2   |Multiple Choice        |MultiValues  |


SCALE VALUES
|Question_ID | Min | Max |
--------------------------
|1           | 1   |10   |

MULTI VALUES
|Question_ID | Name    | Value |
--------------------------------
|2           | Sugar   |  10   |
|2           | Milk    |  20   |
|2           | Egg     |  14   |
```

So from now on, if a question is a "Multiple choice" type, than I want to check the table MULTI VALUES, else the SCALE VALUES. I can do it with stored procedure or I can just query the all the *SOMETHING* VALUES tables for the question_ID. But is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Not really, are you using an ORM? Did something very similar recentky, but took much of the pain out of it with ActiveRecord's polymorphic association.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly design your database that way. However you can't grab the "ExtraValues" column in a query and have that automagically pull in that table into a query. Not without dynamically executed sql. You're best bet is just use branching logic on the question type and use that to determine where to get other related data.

You could also move the min and max fields into the QUESTION table and do away with the ScaleValues table completely. You could just set the to NULL if it's a multiple choice question.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is definetely a better way to do it.  Set up a many to many relationship between questions and available answers.  Add a third column, named points.  So your three tables would be:

Question - QuestionId and Text

Answer - AnswerId and Text

QuestionAnswer - QuestionId, AnswerId, and Points.

Award 0 points for wrong answers.

This design might be too simple.  You might need a Test Table as well.  Then you would need a TestId field in that many to many table, which would now be called, TestQuestionAnswer.